# SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest() In SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server

I want to know, In which situation should i use **"SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest()"**. According to articles we have to use it while we updating the database using POST Request, But there are no sample code. So i want some **code sample or example.**

Please help. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: That article should help you: https://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2008/05/21/what-you-need-to-know-about-allowunsafeupdates-part-2/.

Answer (score 3):

I use that in aspx pages before running code with elevated privileges:

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
   <SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server"/>
   <asp:Button id="Button1" style="Z-INDEX: 101; LEFT: 282px; POSITION: absolute; 
      TOP: 282px" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="BtnSaveClick" ></asp:Button>
</form>
```

---

```
protected void BtnSaveClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Page.IsValid && SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest())
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite curSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = curSite.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
                {
                      this.CreateAndSendTask(); //just an example
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. But but here what is the need of using SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest()?

Comment: It's used to revalidate the page security. This will ensure that the post request is validated (that it is not a cross-site scripting attack) and after that you will not have to worry about AllowUnsafeUpdates, because its default value will be “true” after the form digest is validated.